# Why is nohup still causing a process being run in a shell script to terminate?

Tags: android, bash, busybox, nohup

I am logging the data coming from `top` and putting it into a circular set of files.  I am not executing `top` for one set of data and then rerunning for the next set, but instead using a read time out to specify when to go from one log file to the next.  This is primarily done this way to remove the startup CPU load cost every time `top` is executed.  The shell script file's name is toplog.sh and looks similar to this:

```
#!/data/data/com.spartacusrex.spartacuside/files/system/bin/bash

date
echo "  Logging started."

fileCmp()
{
  test `ls -lc "$1" | sed -n 's/\([^ ]* *\)\{4\}\([0-9]*\).*$/\2/;p'` $2 $3
}

oldest()
{
  ls -rc $1 2> /dev/null |head -1
}

file=`oldest /mnt/sdcard/toplog.\*.gz`
echo "  Oldest file is $file"
if [ -z "$file" ]; then
  x=0
else
  file=${file%%.gz}
  file=${file##*.}
  x=$file
fi
echo "  x=$x"

top -d 20 -b  | \
  while true; do
    file=/mnt/sdcard/toplog.$x.gz
    while read -t 5 line; do
      echo "$line"
    done | gzip -c > $file
    if fileCmp "$file" -le 300; then
      date
      echo "        Failure to write to file '$file'."
      exit
    fi
    x=$((($x+1)%10))
    sleep 14
  done
```

I execute this using nohup so that when the shell dies, this process still runs, like so:

```
$ nohup ./toplog.sh
```

But there's a problem.  `top` terminates when I exit the shell session that executed that command, and I'm not exactly sure why.  Any ideas?

To clarify, I'm logging on a Android phone. The tools are limited in functionality (i.e. lack some of these switches) and is why I am using top as it contains the output I want.

Version of busybox I'm using is:

```
BusyBox 1.19.2 (2011-12-12 12:59:36 GMT)
```

Installed when I installed Terminal IDE.

BTW, this phone is not rooted.  I'm trying to track down a failure when my phone responds as if the CPU has spiked and won't go down.

**Edit:**
Well, I found a workaround. But the reason is a bit hazy. I think it has to do with process management and smells of a bug in the busybox ver that I'm using that was missed during regression testing.

The workaround is to wrap `top` with a useless loop structure like this: `while true; do top; done`. Through testing, `top` never gets killed and never gets respawned, but by wrapping it up, it isn't killed.

Any insights on this?

Comment: It is probably something to do with the controlling terminal being closed/disconnected.  Does `top` work when its standard input is `/dev/null`?  Does it work when its standard error is sent to `/dev/null`?  That would leave only standard output to be piped to the `while true` loop.

Comment: use ps instead of top; top tends to like graphical things afaik.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I'm logging on a phone.  Android to be precise.  The tools are limited in functionality (i.e. lack some of these switches) and is why I am using top as it contains the output I want.

Comment: Hmm, if it's Android, then I'm not sure how that script could work. First, there's usually no `/bin/bash`, then '/tmp' is usually not writeable. Does this script work without `nohup`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  This was the pre-ported code.  I'll update.

Comment: have you manually installed bash? how are you running this?

Comment: sorry I think this is a problem of your port - this works for me specifically

Comment: What about `nohup bash toplog`?

Comment: @Adrian Please mention what's your shell and where do the tools come from. Is it `busybox`, maybe coming from SSHDroid? Or do you have the stock tools in your PATH, i.e. `mksh` and `toolbox`?

Comment: @Adrian Please check if you get anything in `nohup.out` after the script stops.

Comment: @Adrian Please check if the script executes without `nohup` as well.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf: I think you are right about a prob with the port.  This works under Ubuntu.

Comment: @M.Elmi: no, that doesn't work either.

Comment: also @Adrian if you look at pstree it doesn't terminate even after you close your shell

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf: were you running under Android or other OS?

Comment: @Adrian To clarify, I tried running your script on my Galaxy S2 with SSHDroid (busybox 1.18.5) and it works.

Comment: @Adrian i'm running Debian 7.0 :P so that's why it's not a bash problem.

Comment: @spbnick: it runs correctly, but does it detach and continue executing when you close the shell or terminal?

Comment: @Adrian Yes. I run it with `nohup ./top_watch &` and it stays there and continues working. Please check if there is anything in `nohup.out` after it terminates.

Comment: No, there wasn't.  My code is somewhat different as it checks the log files just written to, and terminates if the log is empty echoing a message to stdout which goes to `nohup.out`.  But before that, I did look at the `nohup.out` and was confused by the failure as there wasn't anything reported.

Comment: @Adrian Please post the exact code you run on your device, you might be missing something.

Comment: @spbnick doubtful as it works on many other platforms, but I'll do it anyway.

Comment: I've got to go for a bit.  Currently, it would appear that it is a busybox failure.  I'll have to confirm this later.

Comment: @Adrian Your updated script still works for me. I highly doubt it's a busybox failure. As you do not mention putting nohup into background and it's not clear how you close the terminal, please consider @WhyteWolf answer. I.e. check that you run the `nohup` command with `&` on the end, or press Ctrl-Z before closing the terminal.

Comment: did both putting it in the bg and leaving in the fg.  same failure.

Comment: @Adrian Try running `nohup` under `strace` to see what the last system calls where. Maybe this will give you some idea.

Comment: @spbnick `strace` doesn't exist under this busybox environment. :(

Answer (score 1):

going to sound stupid, but change your startup command from

```
nohup ./toplog.sh
```

to

```
nohup ./toplog.sh &
```

the & makes it run as a background process further removing it from the terminal stack.

Comment: nope - his code works correctly on ubuntu and debian; this is an android specific port or OS problem.

Comment: The problem is that `top` terminates when I close the terminal.

Comment: I tested this on centos before posting my answer. and had it fail as the user was failing, and now i don't however there was one difference. when it failed i had hit ctrl+c then ctrl+d close the terminal cleanly, since control of the terminal was arrested by the script. if i just close the terminal it didn't die.

Comment: is centos a busybox app/install or a phone?  Edit: Never mind.  Yes, it's been confirmed that it works on desktop platforms.

Comment: no, neither is ubuntu. I currently don't have the android SDK installed on my work computer to test on an android device. however i can invoke a busybox version of bash on centos. What you are describing as an issue is top still being attached to the terminal when it is killed.  in what way are you killing the terminal? it is possible that if you are not pushing the process to the background that killing the terminal in busybox even when in nohup still kills the application. which would be different then standard behavior for bash. but a short cut in programming in busybox could cause.

Comment: Neither is Ubuntu?  I don't understand.  Anyway, it does seem to have to do with the terminal being shutdown.  When I run another bash shell, invoke the `nohup ./toplog.sh` and exit, it works fine.  When I kill the terminal application, it shutsdown.  There is a possibility that the terminal app is causing this, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Running the bash internal command "disown" on your script's process before logging off may prevent it from being signaled.

Comment: Isn't disown used for background processes?  `top` isn't a background process from the POV of the shell that runs it.  Or are you saying to disown the shell that is running it?

Comment: Doesn't matter, the `disown` command doesn't exist for my version of `bash`. :(